# Is it possible to re-run Validation stage alone (without re-build) in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to re-run Validation stage alone (without re-build) in VSTS? 
Some of our tests fail intermittently and we would like to Re-run tests (or better just the failed tests) alone to qualify pull request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to re-run validation stage (part of tasks in your build definition) only in VSTS is **using private agent to build, set clean as false in Get sources step and disable the tasks you want to skip**. Detail steps as below:

1. **Specify a private agent for the build definition**

   If you have not a private agent, you can refer the document like [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts), then specify the private agent for your build definition.
2. **Set Clean option as false in Get sources step**

   In Get sources steps, set Clean option as false.

   [image]
3. **Disable the tasks you want to skip for re-build**

   Select the tasks you want to skip -> Disable selected task(s) -> Save build definition.

   [image]
4. **Re-build PR validation build manually**

   In the pull request page -> click `…` button -> Queue build.

   [image]

   Then the PR validation build will be queued with only part of tasks executed.
5. **Recovery the build definition**

   After execute the validation for your debug, then you need to recover and save the build definition.